# LiveData + ViewModel + Room: Exposing a LiveData returned by query which changes over time (Through a fts search)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have an FTS query in my DAO which I'd like to use to provide search in my App. The activity passes the query to view model each time the search text is changed.

The problem is that, Room returns a `LiveData` every single time the query is executed while I'd like to get same `LiveData` object updated when I run the query.

I was thinking about copying data from the `LiveData` which room returns into my `dataSet` *(see the code below)*. Would it be a good approach? (And if yes, how would I actually do that?)

Here's my work so far:

In my Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //....

    wordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WordMinimalViewModel::class.java)

    wordViewModel.dataSet.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let {mRecyclerAdapter.setWords(it)}
    })
}

/* This is called everytime the text in search box is changed */
override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {

    //Change query on the view model
    wordViewModel.searchWord(query)

    return true
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    private val repository :WordRepository =
        WordRepository(WordDatabase.getInstance(application).wordDao())

    //This is observed by MainActivity
    val dataSet :LiveData<List<WordMinimal>> = repository.allWordsMinimal


    //Called when search query is changed in activity
    //This should reflect changes to 'dataSet'
    fun searchWord(query :String?) {
        if (query == null || query.isEmpty()) {

            //Add all known words to dataSet, to make it like it was at the time of initiating this object
            //I'm willing to copy repository.allWordsMinimal into dataSet here

        } else {

            val results = repository.searchWord(query)
            //Copy 'results' into dataSet
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
    //Queries all words from database
    val allWordsMinimal: LiveData<List<WordMinimal>> =
        wordDao.getAllWords()

    //Queries for word on Room using Fts
    fun searchWord(query: String) :LiveData<List<WordMinimal>> =
        wordDao.search("*$query*")

    //Returns the model for complete word (including the definition for word)
    fun getCompleteWordById(id: Int): LiveData<Word> =
        wordDao.getWordById(id)
}
```

DAO:

```
interface WordDao {

    /* Loads all words from the database */
    @Query("SELECT rowid, word FROM entriesFts")
    fun getAllWords() : LiveData<List<WordMinimal>>

    /* FTS search query */
    @Query("SELECT rowid, word FROM entriesFts WHERE word MATCH :query")
    fun search(query :String) :LiveData<List<WordMinimal>>

    /* For definition lookup */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id=:id")
    fun getWordById(id :Int) :LiveData<Word>
}
```

Comment: Could you show code for wordDao

Comment: @ArulMani Thanks for showing interest. I guess the DAO code was pretty obvious to be guessed from the repositiory code. Anyway, I've added that to my question.

Comment: Livedata transformations is what you are looking for. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations.html

Comment: By using transformations, on every query text change you will "swap" the livedata but your observer does not need to take an action and will just keep observing as before.

Comment: Those methods actually use Mediatorlivedata under the hood

Comment: @NezihYılmaz Thanks for your effort. I'll check out Transformations docs right away. It'd really be great if you post an answer with some sort of "rough and abstract code" which I can use.

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val dataSet :LiveData<List<WordMinimal>>

val searchQuery = MutableLiveData<String>()

init {
    dataSet = Transformations.switchMap(searchQuery) { query ->
        if (query == null || query.length == 0) {
            //return WordRepository.getAllWords()
        } else {
            //return WordRepository.search(query)
        }
    }
}


fun setSearchQuery(searchedText: String) {
    searchQuery.value = searchedText
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I actully figured this out with the help of your comment and was about to post it as answer - this is exactly what I used.

Comment: Btw, I also have a problem with my `WordRepository#getAllWords()` it takes a lots of time to display all the items on RecyclerView (like 7 around seconds). I have nearly 170,000 words in my database. Can you possibly help me doing it more efficently? Just asking for a refernce or link. Thanks :)

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni You need to use what we call "paging". Instead of retrieving all 170.000 words, you retrieve just the amount you are going to use. For example, start with fetching first 30 words and when your recyclerview scrolls to end, fetch the next 30 words and add it to recyclerview. I am sure you have seen this pattern before

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni android arch. components does include a paging library to help you with all these logic. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were really very helpful to me today :)